# Write an image dataframe in pyspark

Tags: image, apache-spark, pyspark

Spark recently introduced "image" as supported data type for sources in version 2.4. But I am struggling to find out how to save the data type.
I have to perform a simple image transformation on a lot of images and save the transformed images to another location.

I am using the mmlspark library for transformations. Spark version is 2.4.3.
Here is what I have tried out so far:

Reading the images in PySpark

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("Python Spark SQL basic example") \
    .config("spark.some.config.option", "some-value") \
    .getOrCreate()

df_image = spark.read.format("image").load("car-images")
df_image.printSchema()
```

Output

```
root
 |-- image: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- origin: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- height: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |-- width: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |-- nChannels: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |-- mode: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |-- data: binary (nullable = true)
```

Performing a simple transformation

```
from mmlspark import ImageTransformer
img_transformer = ImageTransformer().setOutputCol("flipped").flip()
flipped_images = img_transformer.transform(df_image).select("flipped")
flipped_images.printSchema()
```

Output

```
root
 |-- flipped: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- origin: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- height: integer (nullable = false)
 |    |-- width: integer (nullable = false)
 |    |-- nChannels: integer (nullable = false)
 |    |-- mode: integer (nullable = false)
 |    |-- data: binary (nullable = false)
```

Trying to save the transformed images to another location

```
flipped_images.write.format("image").save("car-images-flipped")
```

which results in an error that write is not supported for image data type.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-7a8ced5adfe6> in <module>()
----> 1 flipped_images.write.format("image").save("car-images-flipped3")

~/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py in save(self, path, format, mode, partitionBy, **options)
    734             self._jwrite.save()
    735         else:
--> 736             self._jwrite.save(path)
    737 
    738     @since(1.4)

~/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1255         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1256         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1257             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1258 
   1259         for temp_arg in temp_args:

~/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
     61     def deco(*a, **kw):
     62         try:
---> 63             return f(*a, **kw)
     64         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
     65             s = e.java_exception.toString()

~/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329             else:
    330                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o104.save.
: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Write is not supported for image data source
    at org.apache.spark.ml.source.image.ImageFileFormat.prepareWrite(ImageFileFormat.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:103)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:159)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:104)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:102)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:122)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:668)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:668)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:668)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:276)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:270)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:228)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

How else can I save the transformed images back?